# EKS Cluster authentication issue: User or role used to create the EKS cluster got deleted from AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have a EKS cluster created with eksctl cli tool.

Now the user or role which was used to create the EKS cluster got deleted from AWS IAM and I haven't added any other user the permission to access Kubernetes resources inside the cluster.

I have admin access to my AWS account. Is there a way to get the access to kubernetes cluster resources running inside EKS?

I tried the solution provided in the below article and it didn't workout as the IAM user and role was deleted from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-eks-cluster-access/

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I believe there is a simple solution:

Simply create the IAM User or IAM Role with the same name as previously used for the cluster. Then generate and export User credentials or assume the IAM Role. 
Then simply run

> aws eks update-kubeconfig --name ${cluster_name}

and then you should be able to perform actions against API using kubectl.

Comment: This is the correct answer... But to give a bit more explanation as to why this works.
When the `eksctl` utility is used to create a new cluster, the user who created the cluster is assigned the proper permissions. The user is referenced by its `arn:aws:iam::{your-org-id}:user/{the-deleted-user-name-here}`. So with the creation of a new user, with the same username, the arn that was originally used will once again resolve to a valid user.